# Trying to do an query that runs every hour in BQ

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, bq

So currently, a smart data scientist here set up a query that runs hourly:

```
WHERE creationdate > DATETIME(DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL -60 MINUTE))
```

The creation date is displayed in this format: 2021-11-05T01:32:57

So I just wrote a separate query (different tables) that runs fine if not selected for an interval but fails:

```
TransactionTimestamp >= DATETIME(DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL -60 MINUTE))
```

the error is:

> **No matching signature for operator >= for argument types: TIMESTAMP, DATETIME. Supported signature: ANY >= ANY at [7:5]**

The TransactionTimestamp is displayed in this format:
`2021-11-05 03:14:22 UTC`

I'm just confused how to format that?

Answer (score 0):

'TransactionTimestamp' data type is "TIMESTAMP" while `DATETIME()` fucntion output data type would be  "DATETIME" data type, based on its input args and operator > or < operators can't compare these 2 different data types.

The reason is dateadd() function returns date as output even if you pass timestamp as input parameter, dateadd() gets the timestamp and extract the date from it.

instead, you can use `TIMESTAMP_ADD` function :

```
TransactionTimestamp >= TIMESTAMP_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL -60 MINUTE)
```

Comment: you nailed it. all my love to you

Comment: you are welcome , please accept and upvote if this answer helped